# How to insert data in a joined table with Entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework, join

I am new to Entity Framework and I am hoping for some help to insert data in a "joined table".

I have three tables, `Profiles`, `Tags` and one called `ProfilesTags` that joins these two tables. Classes are autogenerated from database / DB First.

```cs
public partial class Profiles
{
    public Profiles()
    {
        this.ProfilesTags = new HashSet<ProfilesTags>();
    }

    public int ProfileId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<ProfilesTags> ProfilesTags { get; set; }
}


public partial class Tags
{
    public Tags()
    {
        this.ProfilesTags = new HashSet<ProfilesTags>();
    }

    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProfilesTags> ProfilesTags { get; set; }
}

public partial class ProfilesTags
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProfileId { get; set; }
    public int TagId { get; set; }

    public virtual Tags Tags { get; set; }
    public virtual Profiles Profiles { get; set; }
}
```

I have a `SaveTags` method that looks like this:

```cs
public void SaveTags(int profileId, IEnumerable<TagsNameValue> tags)
    {
        var pr = Context.Profiles.First(p => p.ProfileId == profileId);

    // remove any existing
        pr.ProfilesTags.Clear();

        if (tags == null || !tags.Any())
            return;

        var ids = tags.Select(value => value.Value);
        var names = tags.Select(value => value.Name);


        // get a list of tags for lookup from [Tags]-table
        var tagsList = Context.Tags.Where(t => ids.Any(v => t.TagId == v) || names.Any(v => t.Tag == v)).ToList();

        foreach (var nameValue in tags)
        {
            var tag = tagsList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.TagId == nameValue.Value || t.Tag.ToLower() == nameValue.Name.ToLower());

            // Tag is already in [Tags], no need to recreate id, just associate it.
            if (tag != null)
            {
                var tagModel = new ProfilesTags()
                {
                    TagId = nameValue.Value,
                    ProfileId = profileId
                };

                pr.ProfilesTags.Add(tagModel);
            }

            // create new item in [Tags] table first and add association [ProfilesTags]
            else
            {
                var newTag = new Tags { Tag = nameValue.Name};

            // how do I associate this newly added tag to pr.ProfilesTags ?
                // what to do / how to procede?

                Context.Tags.Add(newTag);
            }
        }
        Context.SaveChanges()
    }
```

How can I associate `newTag` with `pr.ProfilesTags`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `newTag` should have a valid id first, then build the relationship by `ProfilesTags` later.

```
// create new item in [Tags] table first and add association [ProfilesTags]
else
{
     var newTag = new Tags { Tag = nameValue.Name};

     // how do I associate this newly added tag to pr.ProfilesTags ?
     // what to do / how to procede?

     Context.Tags.Add(newTag);

     // Let newTag has a valid tagId
     Context.SaveChanges();

     // Build the relationship between `Profiles` and `Tags`.
     var newProfileTag = new ProfilesTags();

     /// Build the relationship by ForeignKey,
     /// Or, call pr.ProfilesTags.Add(newProfileTag)
     newProfileTag.ProfiledId = pr.ProfileId; 
     newProfileTag.TagId = newTag.TagId; //< It SHOULD NOT be zero...
     Context.ProfilesTags.Add(newProfileTag);

     // Save the newProfileTag.....
     // Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this seems to work but then another problem arises. The first time I add a new Tag to ProfilesTags it works. But if I then edit the Profile and just save it without adding new tags (or removing the existing tag), then I get an error - calling `pr.ProfilesTags.Add(tagModel);` i.e. it just adds existing tags to the model.

Comment: Error is 

`The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.`

Comment: As the error message said, the foreign keys, `ProfileId` and `TagId` of `ProfilesTag` **MUST NOT** be null (or zero). If you want to remove an existing `Tags`, you need to remove the related `ProfileTags` first. If the `Cascade Delete` is configured between `Tags` and `ProfileTags`, the database engine will do it automatically.

Comment: When you remove an existing `Tags`, the foreign key `TagId` of related `ProfileTags` will be set to `null` automatically. But your db schema doesn't allow this condition, so you get the error. In order to maintain the `Consistency` of database, maybe you need to delete those related `ProfileTags` before deleting the `Tags`.

Comment: Thank you - I have accepted the answer. Instead of  `pr.ProfilesTags.Clear();` I used  `pr.ProfilesTags.RemoveRange();`. As far as I understand .Clear() is causing the problems because of parent/child relationsship.