# Many-to-Many relationship in Entity Framework Core for Insertion in 3 different tables

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am new to Entity Framework Core, can any one help me how to insert the data in the following table.

```
Student Table
==============
StudentID Int
StudentName Varchar(50)

Class Table
===============
ClassID int
ClassName Varchar(50)

StudentClassXref
==================
StudentID int
ClassID Int
```

The relationship for the above tables will Student Table will have a Foreign key to Xref table only, same applies for the Class table.
There is no direct link between Student and Class table, so once I generated the POCO classes I got the above 3 tables and relationship with Student and Class Table refering only to Xref table.

So Now how to insert data in Student, Class and Xref table.

After saving the Values should be

```
Student
===========
1         xxxxx

Class
============
1        Maths
2        Science

Xref
===========
1         1
1         2
```

Can any one help me how to insert the data to these tables using EF core.

Thanks in advance.

## My POCO Class

```
public partial class Student
{
  public int StudentId { get;  set; }
  public string StudentName { get;  set; }

  public System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<StudentClasseXref> StudentClasseXrefs { get; set; }
  public Equation()
  {
     StudentClasseXrefs = new System.Collections.Generic.List<StudentClasseXref>();
     InitializePartial();
  }
}
```

## Classes POCO

```
public partial class Class
{
  public int ClassId { get;  set; }
  public string ClassName { get;  set; }

  public System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<StudentClasseXref> StudentClasseXrefs { get; set; }
  public Class()
  {
     StudentClasseXrefs = new System.Collections.Generic.List<StudentClasseXref>();
     InitializePartial();
  }
}
```

## Xref POCO Class

```
public partial class StudentClassXref
{
    public int StudentId { get;  set; }
    public int ClassId { get;  set; }

    public Student Student { get; set; }
    public Class Class { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm sure you tried something. Please show your efforts so we can see where *specifically* you need help. Currently it's not clear what you're asking (or why you're asking).

Comment: Currently I am trying to Insert Data First in Student Table by dbContext.Students.Add(student); dbContect.Classes.Add(class); but it inserts fine in Student and Class table, but I am not sure how to insert values in xref table. Where I need to insert as Student ID and Class ID

Comment: Really, it's easier to tell you what do you if we can modify your existing code.

Comment: var student = Mapper.Map<St.Student>(StudentDto);
                ClassesDto cdto = new ClassesDto();
                cdto.Name = "Test";
                var emain = Mapper.Map<St.Classes>(cdto);

                dbContext.Students.Add(student);                                                 
                dbContext.Classes.Add(emain);

Comment: Please edit your question.

Comment: What edit is needed

Comment: I mean: add the code to your question. Code in comments is hard to read.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You can read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx I think the attach method could help you

Comment: Typically students would have a collection of classes and classes would have a collection of students. Sounds like you went more like [this](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/03/12/avoid-many-to-many-mappings-in-orms/) which is fine. You probably want something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28867211/how-to-insert-data-in-a-joined-table-with-entity-framework) where you add or fetch the student, add or fetch the class, then you instantiate a new StudentClass and set the StudentId and ClassId (or navs) and save. Show your POCOs and code - not the DB.

Comment: @SteveGreene Yes. EF-core doesn't support many-to-many associations (with a hidden junction class) so there is no other option.