# How to insert data in a joined table with Entity Framework Core with one save?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Assuming I have the below table/class structure for Entity Framework Core. Is it possible to insert new records with a join table in one call to `SaveChanges`?

I know it can be done with 2 saves (insert TableB > save > insert TableAB > save) and there's a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28867211/how-to-insert-data-in-a-joined-table-with-entity-framework) doing that.

```
public class TableA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TableAB> ABs { get; set; } = null!;
}

public class TableAB
{
    public int TableAId { get; set; }
    public TableA TableA { get; set; } = null!;
    public int TableBId { get; set; }
    public TableB TableB { get; set; } = null!;
}

public class TableB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Aside from the fact that your `TableB` navigation property incorrectly references the `TableA` entity, what's the actual problem?

Comment: Clearly that was a typo and is now corrected . I'm not sure how to rephrase the question really. The problem is I want to avoid executing two saves and would like to construct the object and save to the database with one save. Less calls to the database seems better, if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy to insert multiple related objects with only one save - for example:

```
var b1 = new TableB();
var b2 = new TableB();

context.TableAs.Add(new TableA
{
    ABs = new List<TableAB>
    {
        new TableAB
        {
            TableB = b1,
        },
        new TableAB
        {
            TableB = b2,
        },
    },
});

context.TableAs.Add(new TableA
{
    ABs = new List<TableAB>
    {
        new TableAB
        {
            TableB = b1,
        },
    },
});

context.TableAs.Add(new TableA
{
    ABs = new List<TableAB>
    {
        new TableAB
        {
            TableB = b2,
        },
    },
});

context.SaveChanges();
```

The only slightly complicated part is keeping references to the related entities (`TableB`) when you need to reference them from multiple places.

This assumes that your `Id` properties are all `IDENTITY` columns in the database. If not, you'll need to manually assign them.

Comment: That's great, I don't know why I didn't try assigning the complex object to the property and was just stuck thinking about the Id property in the join table. Good to know that EF handles the insertion of new objects like this .